# Confusion matrix and test accuracy for PyTorch CNN tutorial

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, confusion-matrix, conv-neural-network

I am interested in reporting only train and test accuracy as well as confusion matrix (say using sklearn confusionmatrix). How can I do that? The current tutorial only reports train/val accuracy and I am having hard time figuring how to incorporate the sklearn confusionmatrix code there. Link to original tutorial here: https://github.com/bentrevett/pytorch-sentiment-analysis/blob/master/4%20-%20Convolutional%20Sentiment%20Analysis.ipynb

Comment: Show your efforts and code then ask about where is the bug or error?

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the `binary_accuracy` function defined in the tutorial, you can implement any metric that you want. All you need is a set of model predictions (`preds` in this case) and true targets (`y`).

For example, for confusion matrix, you could do the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def compute_confusion_matrix(preds, y):
    #round predictions to the closest integer
    rounded_preds = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(preds))
    return confusion_matrix(y, rounded_preds)
```